# How to Replace white space in perl

Tags: perl, string

```
chomp($myString);
$myString =~ s/\///g;
```

can i replace those two with

```
$myString =~ s/\s//g;
```

are there any difference? Please explain.

Comment: No, you can't - they don't do anything remotely similar. What are you trying to do?

Comment: chomp() only *defaults* to removing newlines. What chomp() removes depends on the value of the $/ variable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your first code will take a newline off the end of $myString if it exists and then remove all "/" characters. The second line of code will remove all whitespace characters. Is there a typo?

Maybe you want to know you can replace this:

```
chomp($myString);
$myString =~ s/\s//g;
```

with this:

```
$myString =~ s/\s//g;
```

If that's the question, then yes. Since a newline counts as whitespace, the second code example do the job of both lines above.

Comment: Aha.. So i can write
$myString =~ s/\s//g;
$myString =~ s/\///g;

instead of writing all three
chomp($myString);
$myString =~ s/\///g;
$myString =~ s/\s//g;


Am i correct

Comment: @DarRay: yes, unless you've changed the default input record separator.

Answer (score 1):

From perldoc [chomp](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html):

**chomp** remove the newline from the end of an input record when you're worried that the final record may be missing its newline.

When in paragraph mode `($/ = "" )`, it removes all trailing newlines from the string. 
When in slurp mode (`$/ = undef` ) or fixed-length record mode (`$/` is a reference to an integer or the like, see perlvar) **chomp()** won't remove anything.

you can **remove** leading and trailing whitespace from strings like,

```
$string =~ s{^\s+|\s+$}{}g
```

Answer (score 0):

Chomp will get rid of newlines at the end of your string, but won't remove whitespace. A typical trim function uses the following two substitution lines:

```
$string =~ s/^\s+//;
$string =~ s/\s+$//;
```

The first line removes any spaces at the beginning of your string, and the second removes spaces after the end of the string.